# Polar vector as function of arc length

Tags: calculus

Given a polar function $e^\theta$ , how do you express r(s)? i.e., the position of r as a function of arch length. I think this involves a change of variables from $\theta$ to arch length s.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it involves integration but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinitesimal arc length in polar coordinates is given by
$$
\mathrm{d}s = \sqrt{\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2\mathrm{d}\theta^2} = \sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta = \sqrt{2}\,e^\theta\mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
since $r(\theta) = e^\theta$, hence
$$
s = \int_0^s\mathrm{d}s = \sqrt{2}\int_0^\theta e^\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta = \sqrt{2}\,(e^\theta-1)
$$
In consequence, one has $r = e^\theta = 1+\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.